# How to use Entity Framework Wizard for EF 4.0 in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4

[image: vs]

How to set EF 4 Wizard ? The case is like [this](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/536350/Error.mp4)

At this part:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use VS 2015, at VS 2015, there is option to upgrade or downgrade library installed.
The step:

[image: manage]

Then choose downgrade and select expected version

[image]